# MySQL: сортировка численных значений в строковом поле

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Есть такой запрос `SELECT text FROM table_test WHERE text LIKE '%5%'  GROUP BY text` .

Результат выполнения:
`

```
+------------+
|  text      | 
+------------+
|  AS.9.5    |
|  AS.8.5    |
|  AS.7.5    |
|  AS.6.5    |
|  AS.5.5    |
|  AS.5.4    |
|  AS.5.3    |
|  AS.5.2    |
|  AS.5.1    | 
|  AS.3.5    |
|  ASK.29.5  |
|  ASK.29.25 |
|  ASK.29.15 |
|  AST.28.5  |
|  AST.28.25 |
|  AST.28.15 |
|  AS.20.5   |
|  AS.2.5    |
|  ASDA.19.5 |
|  AB-B-5.1  |
|  AB-B-5.3  |
|  AB-B-5.4  |
|  AB-B-13.5 |
|  AB-B-15.8 |
```

Как сделать так, чтобы при вводе цифры 5, сначала выводились данные, которые начинаются с 5? А после этого в этом же запросе выводились данные, начиная с самого маленького значенния и до последнего.
Например:

```
+------------+
|  text      | 
+------------+
|  AS.5.1    |
|  AS.5.2    |
|  AS.5.3    |
|  AS.5.4    |
|  AS.5.5    |
|  AB-B-5.1  |
|  AB-B-5.3  |
|  AB-B-5.4  |
|  AS.2.5    |
|  AS.3.5    |
|  AS.7.5    |
|  AS.8.5    |
|  AS.9.5    |
|  AB-B-13.5 |
|  AB-B-15.8 |
|  ASK.20.5  |
|  ASK.28.5 |
|  ASK.29.15 |
```

Comment: Это всё ещё не строгое описание формата... Есть левая часть и правая(число). Может ли в левой части быть что-то кроме букв, знаков "-" и "."? В правой части обязательно есть дробная часть?

Comment: Как быть например с такими значениями: `ASK1`; `AKS.0`, `AS101-0.1`;  `102`;

Comment: @pegoopik Варианты могут быть AS.2, AS.2.2, AS.12.2. Тоже самое если в левой части будут 3 буквы. Также такой вариант присутсвует. ASK.-2.1, AS-SK-.2.2, AS-A.-2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При условии, что у вас строка формата "XXX.число", где XXX - некий набор символов не содержащий символ ".", можно отсортировать так:

```
SELECT text 
FROM table_test 
WHERE text LIKE '%5%'  
GROUP BY text
ORDER BY 
  --сначала числа, которые начинаются на 5.
  IF(SUBSTR(text, LOCATE('.', text) + 1) LIKE '5%', 0, 1),
  --затем по возрастанию чисел. 
  CAST(SUBSTR(text, LOCATE('.', text) + 1) AS DECIMAL(20, 6))
```

**UPD:**
Так и не понял всех ваших ограничений.
В итоге реализовал такой алгоритм:

```
Анализируем строку справа на лево.
Считаем, что перед числом обязательно есть разделитель("-" или ".").
Проверяем что после разделителя находятся только символы "0-9" и ".".
Если данные некорректные - получим в качестве правой части пустую строку.
Подробно описывать не буду. просто посмотрите результат запроса:
```

запрос:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
SELECT T.*, CAST(
  CASE 
    WHEN right_part_dif NOT RLIKE '[^0-9.]' THEN right_part_dif
    WHEN right_part_dot_2 NOT RLIKE '[^0-9.]' THEN right_part_dot_2
    WHEN right_part_dot_1 NOT RLIKE '[^0-9.]' THEN right_part_dot_1
    ELSE ''
  END AS DECIMAL(20, 6)) right_part
FROM(
SELECT text, 
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, '-', -1)right_part_dif,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, '.', -1)right_part_dot_1,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(text, '.', -2)right_part_dot_2
FROM(
            SELECT 'ASK.53.05' text
  UNION ALL SELECT '102'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A1.104'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'A123'
  UNION ALL SELECT '123A'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'AKS-1/-0'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'ASK.123'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'ASK-123-1253'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'ASK.123-1253.123'
)T)T)T
ORDER BY IF(text LIKE '%5%', 0, 1), right_part
```

результат:

```
text            right_part_dif  right_part_dot_1    right_part_dot_2    right_part
ASK.53.05           ASK.53.05   05                  53.05               53.050000
ASK-123-1253        1253        ASK-123-1253        ASK-123-1253        1253.000000
ASK.123-1253.123    1253.123    123                 123-1253.123        1253.123000
123A                123A        123A                123A                0.000000
AKS-1/-0            0           AKS-1/-0            AKS-1/-0            0.000000
A123                A123        A123                A123                0.000000
102                 102         102                 102                 102.000000
A1.104              A1.104      104                 A1.104              104.000000
ASK.123             ASK.123     123                 ASK.123             123.000000
```

Возможно этот запрос решает более общую задачу. При необходимости сможете упростить. Но по крайней мере на данных из примера в вопросе он ведёт себя правильно.

Comment: а разве _CAST(text AS FLOAT)_ приведет в число строку вида _AST.28.15_?

Comment: @Grundy, невнимательно посмотрел данные в вопросе, поправил.

Comment: мне кажется и с `IF` тоже надо поправить, строка же с букв начинается, значит _text LIKE '5%'_ - всегда false

Comment: @Grundy,   уже )            .

Comment: @pegoopik Спасибо за ответ! Но возникает ошибка #1054 - Unknown column 'S' in 'order clause'

Comment: @Pavel, поправил. 'S' - с моего примера на локальной машине осталось)

Comment: @pegoopik А можно ли добавить ещё строку формата вида AS-B-5.3, Чтобы они тоже сортировались сразу за боком AS.5.1  и тд?

Comment: @Pavel, опишите строго формат строки в вопросе. Конечно можно, если знать формат.

Comment: @pegoopik Изменил вопрос. Добавил:  AB-B-5.1, AB-B-5.3 , AB-B-5.4,  AB-B-13.5,  AB-B-15.8